# Promise inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I am trying to create a utility service that will help other developers in my team, to execute specific queries, but without the hassle of opening and closing connections.

This is what i wrote:

```js
module.exports.connect = function(runner){
  var connection; 
  return MongoClient.connect(url)
  .then( conn => {
    connection = conn;
    var db = connection.db('looladb');
    return db;
  })
  .then (db => runner(db))
  .then (() => connection.close())
  .catch(err => console.log('Error with mongo query', err));
}
```

and this is the usage pattern:

```js
mongoClient.connect(db => {
  db
   .collection("users")
   .find({email: "shani@gmail.com"})
   .toArray()
   .then(out => console.log('db result', out))
 })
```

This is nice, but I want the usage pattern to be like this -

```js
mongoClient.connect()
  .then(db => {
    db
      .collection("users")
      .find({email: "shani@gmail.com"})
      .toArray()
      .then(out => console.log('db result', out))
  })
```

Comment: in both your "usage pattern" and "desired usage pattern", you have `var result = db. ....` but result is never used for anything, what's the point of it

Comment: I will remove the "result", though keep in mind that this is why i need it as a promise, i want to access the result from the caller (e.g. running getUsers which is using under the hood the utility) but the caller to the get can define what should be done with the results

Comment: not saying you have to remove anything, just that the way you presented the code made no sense - it's not like that `var result` is accessible outside the `.then`

Comment: If you want a utility method that both connects and closes, then any db work you want to do must be sanwiched between `.connect()` and `.close()`. So you *must* pass in the work to be performed - ie `runner`. I don't think there's any escaping the usage pattern you wish to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for the use of [finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally).

```
module.exports.connect = async () => {
  const connection = await MongoClient.connect(url);
  return new Promise(res => res(connection.db('looladb')))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error with mongo query', err))
    .finally(connection.close)
}
```

**Note** - as pointed out, `finally` isn't officially supported yet on Node but can be enabled via the `--harmony-promise-finally` flag. Alternatively, there are other packages you can use for support e.g. [promise.prototype.finally](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.prototype.finally) or [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html)

Comment: also `return new Promise(() => connection.db(‘looladb’))` guarantees a permanently pending promise

Comment: @JaromandaX whoops, autopilot on the hanging promise (written on small screen so didn't verify anything). On the lack of support, I've updated the answer with some options.

Comment: So I am still lost here, @JaromandaX - what do you suggest to do? as i need to get the results (when running get())

Comment: @rabashani as per my update you can simply use a polyfill or enable the flag until Node releases full support.

Comment: @rabashani - not sure why you are asking me, this isn't my answer, I merely pointed out a couple of flaws in the original answer